# Reset/ or Clear the content of CalendarDatePicker and TimePicker in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

how can I reset or clear the content of CalendarDatePicker and/or TimePicker in UWP? I want to create a button (ex. RESET), when I click on the button, the CalendarDatePicker and TimePicker will clear the date and time which was selected before and will show back the PlaceHolder Text. I could not find any methods to do this. Is there a way? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `Date` property of the `CalendarDatePicker`  or the `SelectedTime` property of the `TimePicker` to `null`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    calendarDatePicker1.Date = null;
    timePicker1.SelectedTime = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, you have to set the SelectedDate for DatePicker or SelectedTime for TimePicker to null.
For example:

```
(FindName("myDatePickerName") as DatePicker).SelectedDate = null;
```